# Why does chkdsk produce "Correcting error in index $I30 for file 33267" and then freeze?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

I am running `chkdsk` like this:

```
chkdsk k: /x
```

I get this error:

> Correcting error in index $I30 for file 33267.

What does it mean? Here's the full problem:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]  
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>chkdsk e: /r  
The type of the file system is NTFS.  
Volume label is RodDrobo.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 5)...
162048 file records processed.  
File verification completed.
   0 large file records processed.
   0 bad file records processed.
   0 EA records processed.
   0 reparse records processed. 
CHKDSK is verifying indexes  
(stage 2 of 5)... 10 percent complete.  
(167130 of 208124 index entries processed) 
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 33267. 
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 33267. <--- it always reaches this spot, then hangs forever
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you just leave the chkdsk to finish what it started, Depending on the size if the drive and the number of files in it, chkdsk can take anywhere between a few hours to a few DAYS!!! It's best to be patient or risk losing the drive.

Comment: my drive is 1 terabyte and its like 50% full with whole lot of git repos and nodemodules it takes only 5 minutes to complete chkdsk [chkdsk D: /F]  it does solve the problem temporarily  but again files goes courpt again once i restart the system

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that's either MFT (master file table) corruption or some bad sectors it can't fix. I'd suggest getting the diagnostic tools from the HDD manufacturer and using those, sincee they're sometimes a bit more informative.

Also have a look at your windows event logs to see if there's messages about the disk failing/having bad sectors etc.

Last time I saw a disk doing that it died shortly afterwards. I'd get all your data off there and get yourself a new disk asap.

Comment: i will try those things, this is on a Drobo, which is basically a external storage that Raids together 4 drives.  Getting the data off of there is not an option, but 1 drive failure I can recover from.  Is there any way to determine exactly which file is corrupated?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You need a Symantec recovery disk<sup>[[1]](https://www-secure.symantec.com/norton-support/jsp/help-solutions.jsp?docid=20091016094409EN&product=home&pvid=f-home&version=1&lg=en&ct=us)[[2]](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH83694)</sup>.

Start your computer from the disk, go to *Analyze* and check the hard drive for errors. Be patient, it can take one hour. That will should it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you please explain how to obtain said recovery disk?

Answer (score 0):

Was seeing this error to but only needed to wait 30mins for it to continue on